# Mongoose saving same document in forEach()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I am trying to create a website to display a few upcoming soccer games for the teams I personally am interested in.

I am using a forEach() in order to cycle through the list of teams ids and for each team call an api to get their upcoming match data and save it into a mongodb collection using mongoose save()

I am experiencing an **error where the same document is being saved multiple times and saved in a random order**, even though I wrote code to combat this. I am thinking that there might be some fundamental errors regarding async I have made suchm as I am still learning node.js.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var request = require("request");
const Match = require("../models/matchSchema");
const moment = require("moment-timezone");

const team_id = [
  "40", //liv
  "33", //utd
  "47", //tot
  "49", //chel
  "541", //Real
];

const newMatches = () => {
  team_id.forEach((element) => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/fixtures",
      qs: {
        team: element,
        next: "1",
      },
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "v3.football.api-sports.io",
        "x-rapidapi-key": <myAPIkey>,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    request(options, async (error, response, body) => {
      data = JSON.parse(body);
      if (error) throw new Error(error);

      const newMatch = await Match.findOne({
        outcomeID: data.response[0].fixture.id,
      });

      //to ensure the match doesnt exist

      if (!newMatch) {
        const newMatchCreate = await Match.create({
          outcomeID: data.response[0].fixture.id,
          category: "soccer",
          team1: data.response[0].teams.home.name,
          team2: data.response[0].teams.away.name,
          timeStart: moment
            .utc(data.response[0].fixture.date)
            .format("MM-DD HH:mm"),
        });
        await newMatchCreate.save();
      }
    });
  });
};

module.exports = newMatches;
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have put `await` to make your calls to synchronize your calls to `Match.create()` and `save()` on the new object which i guess writes to a file.  But you have overlooked that the `request()` call is async, and only runs its callback function when the server answers its request. So the whole loop probably completes before the first callback to request is run. Then the file or files are saved in whatever order.

I can't tell exactly what is going on and what you expect so i'm not sure what should write the file or files and when but make sure the data you are assuming is there is there as expected by logging it as soon as it comes in or before you iterate or whatever.